# Go Package dependency layout

Tags: go, dependency-management

In Go, is it best practice to have packages depend on their sub-packages or the other way around?  Obviously you can't have both because that would introduce a circular dependency.

For example

```
└── a
  ├── a.go
  ├── b
    └── b.go
```

Should a depend on b, or should b depend on a?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use both approach. Package may depend on sub-packages, and a sub-package may depend on the *parent* package, as long as there is no circular dependency. There are examples in the standardlib, e.g:

1. Package [`image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/) depends on [`image/color`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color), while package [`image/draw`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/draw) depends on package `image`.
2. Package [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) depends on package `encoding`
3. etc...

Comment: Which you use will mostly depend on circumstances. There is no "right" or "wrong" way.